# Modify html before it gets templated

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, mustache

I am using **Mustache** template script to render my `JSON` values. 
I was wondering : Since I need to bind `data` to the `html` I'm  rendering , there is a way to apply `.data()` to the `object` I'm going to render?

I explain it better with some code :

```
var temp = $("#template").html(),
     obj = Mustache.render(temp,this);
  //I want to bind data to obj before it gets appended
  $('#appended').append(obj);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify obj before or after you append it.

```
var temp = $("#template").html(),
    obj = Mustache.render(temp,this);

$(obj).data("foo","bar").appendTo('#appended');
```

or

```
var temp = $("#template").html(),
    $obj = $(Mustache.render(temp,this));

$('#appended').append($obj)
$obj.data("foo","bar");
```

If your html doesn't start with a tag, you'll have to parse it first.

```
var temp = $("#template").html(),
    $obj = $( $.parseHTML( Mustache.render(temp,this) ) );

$('#appended').append($obj)
$obj.data("foo","bar");
```

Comment: I tried before asking to select with dollar symbol the object rendered , but the console give syntax error |: because it returns pure html ..

Comment: That shouldn't matter, `$()` can handle pure html, as long as it starts with a tag.

Comment: The next step would be to inspect what is being returned to the `obj` variable.

Comment: I think that with `$.parseHTML` it would work , that was the missing thing ! great!